# Generating DataSet of Strong PseudoPrimes?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Is there a C/C++ library for Number Theory that helps generate a Strong PseudoPrimes w.r.t. an Input base.

I intend to test a Primality Testing Algorithm's performace stastically but I am struggling with a dataset of Strong PseudoPrimes and was unable to find one of Random Strong PseudoPrimes large enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you will want to be working with numbers larger than 64-bits, and so you probably want GMP (see [this page](https://gmplib.org/)). This library is used by much of the software that number theorists use. ([Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/) uses parts of it, and [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) uses it too.)

Note that GMP has a built-in function that tests primality by running several Miller-Rabin tests. It doesn't have a function that allows you to specify the input base, but that could be easily created by copying part of the source code.

Finally, note that the website [factordb.com](http://www.factordb.com) maintains a [list of numbers](http://www.factordb.com/prooffailed.php) that pass a surprisingly large number of iterations of the Miller-Rabin test before failing one. This list might be useful to you, and Arnault (in "Constructing Carmichael Numbers Which are Strong Pseudoprimes to Several Bases") gave an example of a 397-digit composite number for which the smallest strong liar is is $307$.

Comment: Prof. I am still struggling with the approach to generate large Strong Pseudoprimes. The way I am doing is: 1. Generate a random odd number 2. Test if its a strong Pseudoprime wrt. input base 3. If not keep incrementing it by 2 till we get a Strong PseudoPrime. 4. Repeat the process to get another Strong PseudoPrime. 

This is highly impractical to say the least as the numbers can be far apart. Is there a short cut I am missing ?

Comment: It is quite likely that there is a short cut. If you only want spsp's for one base $a$, you could look for composite factors of $\Phi_{n}(a)$ that are relatively prime to $n$ (where $n$ is odd and $\Phi_{n}(x)$ is the $n$th cyclotomic polynomial). For example, $N = 407613774637837876811$ is an spsp to base 3 because it is a composite factor of $\Phi_{65}(3)$.

Comment: If you want multiple bases, you could search for $n = p(2p-1)$ where $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ is prime and $2p-1$ is also prime. For such an $n$, one quarter of the bases $a$ will be strong liars, so your chances are good.

Comment: much thanks Prof. I got the second one. The first i have to get some background (my major is CS).